# "Dataproc Agent Startup Failed" with Initialization Script

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

The below initialization script is intended to install Anaconda, some additional packages, and the genomic analysis toolkit Hail, on a Dataproc cluster. However, upon launching a cluster with it, I am receiving an error "Dataproc Agent Startup Failed." Oddly enough, copying/pasting this code into the terminal as root runs the entire script perfectly fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

ROLE=$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-role)

if [[ "${ROLE}" == 'Master' ]]; then

    # Download and install Anaconda in /home/anaconda2/
    wget -P /home/anaconda2/ https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
    bash /home/anaconda2/Anaconda2-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /home/anaconda2
    chmod -R 0777 /home/anaconda2/

    # Additional packages to install.
    /home/anaconda2/bin/pip install lxml
    /home/anaconda2/bin/pip install jupyter-spark
    /home/anaconda2/bin/pip install jgscm

    # Download current version of Hail for Spark 2.1.0. Currently set to use a default version.
    wget -P /home https://storage.googleapis.com/hail-common/distributions/0.1/Hail-0.1-5306854d2213-Spark-2.1.0.zip

    # Unzip hail and create resources.
    unzip /home/Hail-0.1-5306854d2213-Spark-2.1.0.zip -d /home
    zip -r /home/hail/python/pyhail.zip /home/hail/python/hail

    # Create Jupyter kernel spec file.
    mkdir /home/anaconda2/share/jupyter/kernels/
    mkdir /home/anaconda2/share/jupyter/kernels/hail
    echo '{"display_name": "Hail", "language": "python", "argv": ["/home/anaconda2/bin/python", "-m", "ipykernel", "-f", "{connection_file}"], "env": {"SPARK_HOME": "/usr/lib/spark/", "PYTHONHASHSEED": "0", "SPARK_CONF_DIR": "/home/hail/conf/", "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/lib/spark/python/:/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip:/home/hail/hail/python/pyhail.zip"}}' > /home/anaconda2/share/jupyter/kernels/hail/kernel.json

    # Copy the Spark configuration files to a custom directory.
    mkdir /home/hail/conf
    cp /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf /home/hail/conf/spark-defaults.conf
    cp /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh /home/hail/conf/spark-env.sh

    # Modify custom Spark conf file to reference Hail jar and zip
    echo 'spark.files=/home/hail/lib/hail-all-spark.jar' >> /home/hail/conf/spark-defaults.conf
    echo 'spark.submit.pyFiles=/home/hail/lib/hail-all-spark.jar' >> /home/hail/conf/spark-defaults.conf
    echo 'spark.driver.extraClassPath=./hail-all-spark.jar' >> /home/hail/conf/spark-defaults.conf
    echo 'spark.executor.extraClassPath=./hail-all-spark.jar' >> /home/hail/conf/spark-defaults.conf

    # Add Spark variable designating Anaconda Python executable as the default on driver, in both custom and default conf files.
    echo 'PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/home/anaconda2/bin/python' >> /home/hail/conf/spark-env.sh
    echo 'PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/home/anaconda2/bin/python' >> /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh

    # Create Jupyter configuration file.
    mkdir /home/anaconda2/etc/jupyter/
    echo 'c.Application.log_level = "DEBUG"' >> /home/anaconda2/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
    echo 'c.NotebookApp.ip = "*"' >> /home/anaconda2/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
    echo 'c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False' >> /home/anaconda2/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
    echo 'c.NotebookApp.port = 8123' >> /home/anaconda2/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
    echo 'c.NotebookApp.token = ""' >> /home/anaconda2/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
    echo 'c.NotebookApp.contents_manager_class = "jgscm.GoogleStorageContentManager"' >> /home/anaconda2/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

    # Setup jupyter-spark extension.
    /home/anaconda2/bin/jupyter serverextension enable --user --py jupyter_spark
    /home/anaconda2/bin/jupyter nbextension install --user --py jupyter_spark
    /home/anaconda2/bin/jupyter nbextension enable --user --py jupyter_spark
    /home/anaconda2/bin/jupyter nbextension enable --user --py widgetsnbextension

    # Create the systemd service file for Jupyter notebook server process.
    echo '[Unit]' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo 'Description=Jupyter Notebook' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo 'After=hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager.service' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo '[Service]' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo 'Type=simple' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo 'User=root' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo 'Group=root' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo 'WorkingDirectory=/home/hail/' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo 'ExecStart=/home/anaconda2/bin/python /home/anaconda2/bin/jupyter notebook --allow-root' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo 'Restart=always' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo 'RestartSec=1' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo '[Install]' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service
    echo 'WantedBy=multi-user.target' >> /lib/systemd/system/jupyter.service


    # Add Jupyter service to autorun and start it.
    systemctl daemon-reload
    systemctl enable jupyter
    service jupyter start

    # Sleep for 30 seconds to allow Jupyter notebook server to start.
    sleep 30

fi
```

Has anyone encountered this error previously? Normally, Google cloud would tell you where the error logs are, but there is no  additional information regarding this message.

Exceptions in `/var/log/google-dataproc-agent.0.log`:

```
# FIRST:
WARNING: exception thrown while executing request
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getObject(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1727)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getItemInfo(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1618)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.open(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:550)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.open(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:531)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.ClusterPropertiesModule.provideClusterProperties(ClusterPropertiesModule.java:52)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.ClusterPropertiesModule$$FastClassByGuice$$52db3948.invoke(<generated>)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:264)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$Factory.provision(ProviderMethod.java:401)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$Factory.get(ProviderMethod.java:376)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$Factory.provision(ProviderMethod.java:402)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$Factory.get(ProviderMethod.java:376)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.ClusterPropertiesModule.provideFallbackProperties(ClusterPropertiesModule.java:89)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.ClusterPropertiesModule$$FastClassByGuice$$52db3948.invoke(<generated>)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:264)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$Factory.provision(ProviderMethod.java:401)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$Factory.get(ProviderMethod.java:376)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.invoke(FactoryProvider2.java:776)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.protocol.$Proxy17.getAgentApiClientWithEndpoint(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.protocol.AgentServiceClientFactory.get(AgentServiceClientFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.protocol.AgentServiceClientFactory.get(AgentServiceClientFactory.java:20)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentMain.boot(AgentMain.java:58)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentMain.main(AgentMain.java:46)



# SECOND
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/etc/google-dataproc/startup-scripts/dataproc-initialization-script-0": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.util.NativeAsyncProcessWrapperFactory.startAndWrap(NativeAsyncProcessWrapperFactory.java:33)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.util.NativeAsyncProcessWrapperFactory.startAndWrap(NativeAsyncProcessWrapperFactory.java:27)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.BootstrapActionRunner.runScriptAndPipeOutputToGcs(BootstrapActionRunner.java:252)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.BootstrapActionRunner.runSingleCustomInitializationScriptWithTimeout(BootstrapActionRunner.java:127)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.BootstrapActionRunner.runCustomInitializationActions(BootstrapActionRunner.java:114)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AbstractAgentRunner.runCustomInitializationActionsIfFirstRun(AbstractAgentRunner.java:150)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.MasterAgentRunner.initialize(MasterAgentRunner.java:165)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AbstractAgentRunner.start(AbstractAgentRunner.java:68)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.MasterAgentRunner.start(MasterAgentRunner.java:36)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentMain.lambda$boot$0(AgentMain.java:63)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentStatusReporter.runWith(AgentStatusReporter.java:52)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentMain.boot(AgentMain.java:59)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentMain.main(AgentMain.java:46)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: I should note that image version 1.1 of dataproc is necessary for this to run the notebooks properly.

Comment: The default timeout for an initialization action is 10 minutes - when running the script manually did it execute for nearly that long? When using gcloud, this can be changed with --initialization-action-timeout=TIMEOUT

Comment: If init action fails or timesout it is usually reported as such, "Dataproc Agent Startup Failed" is symptomatic of agent initialization failure. Only way to know for sure would be to take a look at `/var/log/google-dataproc-agent.0.log`. Feel free to add any exceptions from there to the question

Comment: The error is onsetting fairly quickly (around a minute). It looks like it's hitting a timeout and a file not found exception (I'm assuming the timeout is causing the file not found), which is odd as it checks for the init script's existence on cluster launch. Edit: The file not found is what is causing dataproc to throw the `com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.AgentException: Dataproc Agent startup failed (INTERNAL)`

Comment: Hmm - I mirrored the script identically in a Python initialization script and it is now running correctly. Sadly, that is only a workaround and doesn't explain the above issue.

Comment: Second error is rather telling. Please confirm that (a) the GCS path is correct and (b) the service account used by the VM has access to read from the init action in GCS

Comment: I was able to successfully execute: `gsutil cp gs://bucket/path/to/init/script.sh /local/directory` from the master node of a cluster which ran into the error. I believe being able to successfully execute this command verifies both of those criteria.